# Can not access button

Tags: java, android, button, android-studio

Good Day

I want to try some stuff with Android Studio (im oretty new in java)
So what I want to do is a Tic-Tac-Toe.
I have created a button and want to assign this button a function.

```
public class TicTacToe extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tic_tac_toe);
        /*Button i created*/
        Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tic_tac_toe, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onClick(View view){
        btn1 /*is not recognized. and here i want the button to do something. but its 
        not possible. Where is the mistake?*/
    }
}
```

Here the xml

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:onClick="changeText"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1" />
```

Do you guys have any idea?
Am I doing errors in reasoning?
Thanks in advance
FIISHxMAN

Answer (score 0):

Change the button to an instance variable.

```
public class TicTacToe extends ActionBarActivity {
Button btn1;
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tic_tac_toe);
    /*Button i created*/
    Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               //Here goes the stuff you want to do when the button is clicked
            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `onClick` property to your button in XML, and then call that function(method) in activity.

Other way would be finding view by id, and adding listener programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you did not paste the full xml(As I analysed) because I am not able to see the button view, I just see the TextView.

Secondly You implement

```
Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

but did not implement the

```
btn1.setOnClickListner(new OnClickListner(){

 @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               //Here goes the stuff when oyu clicked
            }

});
```

Third you implement

```
public void onClick(View view){
    btn1 /*is not recognized. and here i want the button to do something. but its 
    not possible. Where is the mistake?*/
}
```

but you I don't know that you set the onClick method in xml like

```
anroid:onClick = "onClick"
```

Neither you implements onCLickListner interface at class level

**You just simply add**

```
anroid:onClick = "buttonClick"
```

and implement

```
public void buttonClick(View view){
    //Do you task on button click
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a method

`public void handleButtonClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }`

no need to change anything in your code and you are good to go